# Android: Navigation Drawer Z-index incorrect

Tags: java, android, xml, z-order

I have created a Navigation Drawer "BaseActivity" to be extended by multiple activities however when I open the Navigation Drawer none of the menu items can be clicked, there is a semi-opaque layer over them which suggests to me the z-order in which they are loaded is incorrect. How would I go about fixing this?

Not enough rep to post image! https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrKsa.jpg

activity_base.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_base_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

content_base.xml

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/activity_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_base_drawer"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

baseactivity.java

```
    package com.example.SNIPCONFIDENTIAL;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.annotation.LayoutRes;
    import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.FrameLayout;

    public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout fullLayout;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
    private int selectedNavItemId;

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {

    fullLayout = (DrawerLayout) 
     getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_base, null);

    FrameLayout activityContainer = (FrameLayout) 
    fullLayout.findViewById(R.id.activity_content);
    getLayoutInflater().inflate(layoutResID, activityContainer, true);


    super.setContentView(fullLayout);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    navigationView = (NavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.navigationView);

    if (useToolbar())
    {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
    else
    {
        toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    setUpNavView();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

    /*    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is 
    present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.base, menu);
    return true;
}*/

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    /*if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }*/

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
        // Handle the camera action
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(BaseActivity.this, 
        createmytimetable_days.class);
        //myIntent.putExtra("key", value); //Optional parameters
        BaseActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) 
    findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

//STUFF FOR ADDING A BUTTON TO THE TOOLBAR
protected boolean useToolbar()
{
    return true;
}

//STUFF FOR ADDING A BUTTON TO THE TOOLBAR
protected void setUpNavView() {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    if( useDrawerToggle()) { // use the hamburger menu
        drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, fullLayout, 
 toolbar,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
                R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        fullLayout.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        drawerToggle.syncState();
    } else if(useToolbar() && getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        // Use home/back button instead
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(getResources()
                .getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_send));
    }
}

//STUFF FOR ADDING A BUTTON TO THE TOOLBAR
protected boolean useDrawerToggle()
{
    return true;
}


}
```

Comment: Why do you have two `NavigationView`s?

Comment: Hi @VeneetReddy, not sure how that slipped in - deleted now. So at the moment I can click the links in the menu but the semi opaque layer remains over the top of the menu items. Am I missing something obvious? (Excuse the beginner questions :))

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is with the Z-index as you said, then you can make it always on top using `bringToFront()` call this method to your DrawerLayout or NavigationView!